# How to adjust the Width of the Mobile Site of Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I created this website and i have a problem with the mobile site. Which it does not fit to the content. How do i need to fix this? i have attached  the css of the responsive below.

I have tried several codes. But it does not fit to the content. The website is smaller than the device. And making the width 100% did not work.

Thanks in Advance

[image: Please check this image]

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px)   {

.content-area {
    float: center;
    width: 100%;
}   
.social-navigation li a::before,
.sidebar-toggle {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.sidebar-toggle {
    height: 46px;
}
.site-title {
    font-size: 32px !important;
}

    }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.content-area {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    }
.site-logo {    
width: 50px;
text-align: left;
    }
.site-title,
.entry-title {
    padding-top:20px;
    font-size: 18px !important;
}
.site-description {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: Post your site link.

Comment: @ManojKumar http://www.colombowroughtiron.com/

Comment: @Gethma I don't see that problem at all. Which page is it?

Comment: @ManojKumar when you open the link from the mobile broswer  and scroll it to left side it shows an empty space.  You can see this from the inspect-responsive view as well.

Comment: It is because of the extra width that the slider produces before loading the image in that container. Try this `.easingslider { overflow: hidden; }` and check if the problem is over.

Comment: @ManojKumar It does. The problem solved. Thank you so much.